# Android API to read the network mode for Android Q and above

Tags: android, android-networking, android-10.0, android-api-levels

I am looking for an **Android API**, which would return the network mode for Q and above. We do have a way to get network mode by **Reflection** using **getPreferredNetworkType** from **TelephonyManager** class. But as per the android policy, we can't use reflection in android Q and above. So currently searching for an Android API that would return the preferred network mode.

> Please let me know if anybody has any idea about it.